# cocos2d-js ios memory usage keeps increasing on each call to director.replaceScene()

Tags: cocos2d-js

each cc.log show around 1 Kb more on the resident memory size

is that normal or I do something wrong?

this is my Scene2 code, and Scene3 is exactly the same except it calls Scene2

`var Scene2Layer = cc.Layer.extend({
        fcount2: 0,
        ctor:function() {
            this._super();
            this.fcount2 = 0;
            cc.log( new Date().toLocaleString() + " : Scene 2 : " + jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("NativeOcClass","callNativeWithReturnString") );
            this.scheduleUpdate();
            return true;
        },
        update:function(dt){
            // fps is set to 30 so we run a new scene every .1 second
            if( ++this.fcount2 == 3 )
                cc.director.replaceScene(new Scene3());
        }
    });
    var Scene2 = cc.Scene.extend({
        onEnter:function() {
            this._super();
            var layer = new Scene2Layer();
            this.addChild(layer);
        }
    });`

I am using cocos2d-x 3.7
and the code to get the resident memory size is the following:

```
    +(NSString *)callNativeWithReturnString{
    struct mach_task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                   MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                   (task_info_t)&info,
                                   &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Memory used: %u K-bytes", info.resident_size / 1000];
    } else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Err task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr)];
    }
}
```

thank you to look at it

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? or got close to solving it?

Comment: No. After answer from ganka below, I did verify that there is no other reference to any of the elements of the scene. Recreated new cocos project replacing app.js with Scene2 and Scene3 that you see up there, plus the jsb call. Nothing else. So I abandon. Other things to do and the app is working anyway. But it came into my mind last week that I should get back to the investigation of that behavior discovered by accident while looking for something else. Why are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the previous screen instance has not been held by any global references. Also we could deference them by setting null to that references immediate after the new screen transition. It will give better result.